# Cosmological constant problem and dark matter theory by Henke

Tags: dark-matter, dark-energy, cosmological-constant

Christian Henke has recently proposed one approach for the solution of the cosmological constant problem and of the dark matter dynamics: 
[Quantum vacuum energy in general relativity](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1140%2Fepjc%2Fs10052-018-5621-7)

Abstract:

> The paper deals with the scale discrepancy between the observed vacuum energy in cosmology and the theoretical quantum vacuum energy (cosmological constant problem). Here, we demonstrate that Einstein’s equation and an analogy to particle physics leads to the first physical justification of the so-called fine-tuning problem. This fine-tuning could be automatically satisfied with the variable cosmological term  $Λ(a)=Λ_0+Λ_1 a^{−(4−ϵ)}
> ,  0<ϵ≪1$,
>   where a is the scale factor. As a side effect of our solution of the cosmological constant problem, the dynamical part of the cosmological term generates an attractive force and solves the missing mass problem of dark matter.

The paper seems to be mathematically correct, but what about the physical point of view of dark matter?